# How to include files like images and others to be installed with an addon in its folder?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I already know how to load an icon for an addon operator. I know that I can manually put that icon in the addon location so it loads.
But how to package images and other files that will be used by the addon, so they install together when an user installs my addon?
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was answered this in a forum:
" make your script an addon module, basically a folder with a init.py script, which may include the entire code, or you can separate code logically into multiple files. Put the image inside the folder and zip the entire dir. On installation, blender will unpack and copy the content to %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.XX\scripts\addons\ (on windows; xx = subversion, i.e. 66)"